# How to create partition just like we can create in Windows

Tags: 15.04

I want  to create partition in ubuntu 15.05 just like it we make in Windows plzz help me

Comment: How do we make it in Windows?

Answer (score 3):

You can install gparted

run from terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

This software is easy tu use and you can find a lots of information how to use it, in the internet.